# Using Android Studio plugins in fully closed network. (ex, FirebaseCloudMessage)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with Android Studio inside private network, which is fully seperated from internet and has no proxy. My current task is to build apk and put it through to test.

Now I'm setting up the firebase cloud message(FCM) and am a little bit familiar with it because I've used FCM a few times.

Two build.gradle files properly are set up, at least in my experience, but 
when I try to build, error log says '**No cached version of com.google.gms:google-service:3.0 available for offline mode'**

As far as I know, the offline mode is actually a cached mode and 
connecting to network at least one time is required to make cache.

How can I get around this build error?

my root build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0'
}
```

app build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-service:11.0.4'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```